# Will the .zip format be supported for Google Documents via drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Right now my application downloads the documents as zip-archive via GData API.

I'd like to switch to the new "exportLinks" feature of drive, but I don't see the zip format 
in the list of supported formats.

Or is there a different way to export documents as HTML including images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no plans to support ZIP export but I just filed a feature so that this can be reviewed by the team and prioritized.

For now you could use the HTML export link, it will get you the Google Document in HTML where all the images are external links hosted on Google servers (some `https://lhX.googleusercontent.com/<longID>` URLs) And then you would have to write a script that would get all these links from the HTML and then fetch them.